# ¿A qué se refiere devolver un valor o no devolverlo en funciones?

Tags: c, funciones

Sé que existen funciones `void` y `return`, pero no sé a qué se refieren con devolver o no, estoy empezando en programación y es en lenguaje `C`.

Answer (score 5):

Cuando vos le ponés void a una función estás especificando que no va a retornar ningún valor (o sea, no devuelve nada).

Se usa cuando querés ejecutar una serie de acciones pero no querés traerte el resultado de todas esas acciones, sino simplemente que se ejecuten.

Por ejemplo, imprimir un texto:

```
public void hacerAlgo(){
  printf("Imprimiendo algo");
}
```

En cambio si querés que la función devuelva algún valor, se indica el tipo. Por ejemplo, un `int`, un `char`, etc.

Lo que te sirve de esto es que si tenés una función que te devuelve un valor, vos podés posteriormente guardarte ese valor en una variable y seguir operando con ese resultado, o pasarle el valor devuelto a una función.

Ejemplo para sumar 2 parámetros pasados a una función:

```
public int suma(int a,int b){
  return a+b
}
```

Comment: De hecho `printf` sí que devuelve un valor: la cantidad de caracteres que se han podido escribir (o un valor negativo en caso de error)... otra cosa es que el la gran mayoría de casos su valor de retorno se ignore, pero sí que devuelve algo ;)

Answer (score 2):

"*¿A qué se refiere devolver un valor o no devolverlo en funciones?*" Literalmente a devolver un valor o no. Una función realiza una serie de operaciones, si como resultado de esa serie de operaciones se obtiene un valor, puede ser de utilidad devolverlo (p.e. para que pueda ser utilizado por otra función como parámetro de entrada).

En C, para devolver un valor, utilizarás la palabra reservada `return` seguido del valor (o la variable que contiene el valor). Por ejemplo, una función que le pasas dos parámetros y devuelve la suma de ambos valores:

```
int sumar(int a, int b) {
    int c = a + b;
    return c;
}
```

Pero no todas las funciones tienen por qué devolver un valor, puede haber funciones que lo único que hagan sea realizar operaciones pero no haga falta devolver nada, en ese caso es cuando serán `void` y no usarán `return`. Por ejemplo, mostrar un mensaje de éxito/error si la llave utilizada para abrir la puerta es la correcta:

```
void abrirPuerta(llave) {
   if (llave == "correcta") {
       mostrarMensajeExito();
   } else {
       mostrarMensajeError();
   }
}
```

En otros lenguajes se hace una diferenciación más clara entre las funciones que devuelven un valor y las que no lo devuelven. Por ejemplo, en el lenguaje de programación Pascal, se llama funciones a las que devuelven un valor y procedimientos a las que no.

Answer (score 0):

> ¿A qué se refiere devolver un valor o no devolverlo en funciones?

Simplemente a que una función puede o no devolver un valor; pero dentro de esta sencilla respuesta hay varias complejidades a tener en cuenta.

#### Tipo de retorno de la función.

El valor devuelto por una función viene determinado por el tipo indicado antes de la función:

> ```
> tipo_retorno funcion(parametro/s);
> ____________
> ```

El `tipo_retorno` puede ser cualquiera de los siguientes:

- `void`: un tipo de retorno especial que indica que no hay retorno. Void significa *vacío* en inglés ([ver segunda acepción](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/void)).
- Tipos fundamentales: cualquiera de los tipos proveídos por el lenguaje (`short`, `unsigned`, `double`, ...);
- Tipos definidos por el usuario: Cualquier tipo definido por el usuario.

#### Devolver un valor permite el uso como expresión.

Una función que devuelva un valor, es decir: cuyo tipo de retorno no sea `void`, puede ser usada en expresiones:

```
int uno() { return 1; }
int dos() { return 2; }
void nada() {}

// Funciones en una expresion
int cinco = dos() + dos() + uno();
// Funciones en una expresion con literales
int once = (cinco * dos()) + uno();
// Funciones en una condicion
if ((uno() + dos()) == 3) printf("Las matematicas no fallan\n");
```

En estas expresiones, las funciones son evaluadas en primer lugar y después se evalúa la expresión de la que forman parte. Así que las expresiones podrían parecerse a:

```
int cinco = 2 + 2 + 1;
int once = (cinco * 2) + 1;
if ((1 + 2) == 3) printf("Las matematicas no fallan\n");
```

Pero una función que **NO** devuelva un valor, es decir: cuyo tipo de retorno **SEA `void`**, **NO** puede ser usada en expresiones:

```
/* Error, una funcion que no devuelve nada
   no puede formar parte de una expresion. */
int uno_mas_nada = uno() + nada();
int dos_por_nada = dos() * nada();
/* Error, una funcion que no devuelve nada
   no es comparable con nada. */
if (nada()) printf("K'thulu ascendera!");
```

Dado que una función cuyo tipo de retorno sea `void` no devuelve valor, las expresiones, anteriores podrían quedar así:

```
int uno_mas_nada = uno() + ;
int dos_por_nada = dos() * ;
if ( ) printf("K'thulu ascendera!");
```

Esto no llega a suceder porque el compilador considera que una función sin retorno en una expresión es un error así que ni siquiera la evalúa.

#### Usando `return` mal.

La instrucción `return` es la que *asigna* el valor de retorno a las funciones cuyo tipo de retorno no sea `void`, así que si `return` es acompañado de una expresión o valor será para usar dicha expresión o valor como valor devuelto por la función; si `return` no es acompañado por una expresión o valor se entiende que devuelve `void` (vacío). Y de hecho así lo define [estándar de C](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf) en la sección `§6.8.6.4 La instrucción return` (la traducción es mía):

> ### 6.8.6.4 La instrucción return
>
> #### Restricciones
>
> 1. Una instrucción **`return`** con una expresión no debe aparecer en una función cuyo tipo de retorno sea **`void`**. Una instrucción **`return`** sin una expresión debe aparecer sólo en funciones cuyo tipo de retorno sea **`void`**.

Según el estándar de C estas funciones no cumplen con las restricciones:

```
// No devuelve nada, pero deberia devolver un numero.
int funcion_int() { printf("Patatas fritas con ketchup y mayonesa, que rico!"); };

// A veces devuelve algo y a veces no.
int funcion_intint(int n)
{
    if (n==4) return 0;
}

// Usa un return vacio, pero no deberia!
int funcion_return_vacio() { return; }

// Se supone que no devuelve nada, pero igualmente lo hace!
void funcion_void() { return 0; }
```

Pero el compilador [tan sólo emite alarmas al respecto](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/M9gSvleESlFtPkke):

> ```
> In function 'funcion_return_vacio':
> warning: 'return' with no value, in function returning non-void [enabled by default]
>  int funcion_return_vacio() { return; }
>                               ^
> In function 'funcion_void':
> warning: 'return' with a value, in function returning void [enabled by default]
>  void funcion_void() { return 0; }
>                        ^
> In function 'funcion_int':
> warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
>  int funcion_int() { printf("Patatas fritas con ketchup y mayonesa, que rico!"); };
>  ^
> In function 'funcion_intint':
> warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
>  }
>  ^
> ```

Y las funciones *funcionan* al ser llamadas:

```
printf("%d\n", funcion_int());
printf("%d\n", funcion_intint(4));
printf("%d\n", funcion_intint(5));
```

Produciendo la siguiente salida:

> ```
> Patatas fritas con ketchup y mayonesa, que rico!48
> 0
> 0
> ```

Lo *sorprendente* es que la llamada a `funcion_int` ha devuelto el valor `48` pese a que no hay ningún `return` en dicha función. Lo que ha sucedido es que la función está usando el valor retornado por [`printf`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) como valor a retornar. Pero las dos llamadas a `funcion_intint` han devuelto `0` pese a que sólo debería devolver ese valor al ser llamada con un número impar... ¿qué está pasando?

Nos hemos encontrado con un [comportamiento indefinido](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comportamiento_indefinido), que está indicado en el [estándar de C](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf) en la sección `§6.9.1 Definiciones de funciones` (la traducción es mía):

> ### 6.9.1 Definiciones de funciones
>
> 12. Si se alcanza el **`}`** que termina la función y el valor de la llamada a la función es usado por el llamante, el comportamiento es indefinido.

En los casos de `funcion_int()` y `funcion_intint(4)` el comportamiento es indefinido pues se ha llegado al final de la función en lugar de salir de la función a través de la instrucción `return`, cuando sucede un comportamiento indefinido puede pasar cualquier cosa: que el código funcione, que se devuelvan valores inesperados o que [salgan demonios disparados de tus fosas nasales](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html).

#### Una excepción a la regla... `main`.

Según el estándar de C, sólo existe una función en que aún requiriendo un valor de retorno la instrucción `return` es opcional. Esta es la función `main`, que como establece la sección `§5.1.2.2.3 Finalización del programa` (la traducción y resaltado son míos):

> ### 5.1.2.2.3 Finalización del programa
>
> 1. Si el tipo de retorno de la función `main` es un tipo compatible con `int`, un retorno de la llamada inicial a la función `main` es equivalente a llamar a la función `exit` con el valor devuelto por la función `main` como argumento; **alcanzar el `}` que finaliza la función `main` devuelve un valor de `0`**. Si el tipo de retorno no es compatible con `int`, el estatus devuelto al llamador es indeterminado.

Así que existe un caso en que está correctamente especificado qué hacer cuando una función que debiera devolver un valor no lo devuelve, una excepción específica para `main`.